# ActionExecutingContext ActionDescriptor doesn't contain ActionName and MethodInfo

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

As you below can see, in my ActionFilter, I try to get the ActionName and the MethodInfo of the ActionExecutingContext.ActionDescriptor.
But the compiler says that ActionDescriptor doesn't contain a definition for ActionName and MethodInfo. But if I debug the application, I can see, that the ActionDescriptor contains these properties (see pics below).
I'm using ASP .NET Core and I have no idea, where the problem could be.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to cast it to [ControllerActionDescriptor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllers.controlleractiondescriptor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) since that class has the properties you need.

```
var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
var actionName = descriptor.ActionName;
var methodInfo = descriptor.MethodInfo;
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi , How can you determine that you need to cast it to ControllerActionDescriptor without using StackOverflow? I can use this code at run time but is there a way to do it at design time?  
            System.Type t = context.ActionDescriptor.GetType();